# Doing formulas on sequent calculus

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, sequent-calculus

JAre we allowed to equivalence rules on sequential calculus that isn't structural or logical, for example, can I do deMorgans on the red arrow to make it ~p1 ∧ ~p2 |-- ~p2?
[Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UN7y5.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "are we allowed" means you are working in some specific system which gives deduction rules. For an answer here, you need to specify one such system (give its rules etc.)

Comment: No De Morgan's laws in SC. You have to work bottom-up to arrive at axioms $p_2 \vdash p_2$.

Answer (score 1):

No you usually cannot, unless that is a rule itself.

That is, if $$ \lnot ( \phi_1 \lor \phi_2) \vdash  \lnot \phi_1 \land \lnot \phi_2$$
is already given one of the proof rules in your calculus, you can use it.

Otherwise, no. You are only allowed to use the given SC rules.